# Constant Scroll Carousel on hover

Tags: scroll, carousel, continuous

I've written a carousel script with a few options on how it funcitons, and i'm now trying to adapt the ability for it continuously scroll when you hover over one side of the gallery container. I feel like I'm very close, however I'm getting some easing errors and it doesn't quite function 100% right. The demo is here:

http://dev.cmacvet.com (scroll down to Pet Photo Gallery)

The JS is here: http://dev.cmacvet.com/themes/cmac2012/js/jquery.bcarousel.js

My problem is somewhere around line 140 in the move function, or maybe I have my events wrong. I can't seem to keep the movement constant while on hover. I may have just been staring at this too long. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rather bind hover event than mousemove...

at line 87 u got $wrapper.bind('mousemove hover', function(e){...
maybe here's the problem? why do you need to bind 2 events?

Comment: Well, the mouse position can change without ever triggering the mouseout event, so they can switch between the left side and the right side, changing the direction of the carousel.

Comment: I've made a few adjustments and it seems to be working a little bit better but you have to keep you mouse in one place and you can't hover over any of the images or it will stop. And I'm still getting easing errors.

Comment: I agree with your point that you need to have 2 events to switch sides, but why did you bind same action on 2 logically different events? I think you need to bind separately mousemove event on the slideshow wrapper do the calculation of finding the center and switch a flag variable, at the same time having another event for mouseover which fires appropriate function depending on what the flag variable value is..

Comment: I have adjusted my binds to accommodate these 2 events separately. It seems I'm very close, but it appears to not want to continuously scroll. BTW, my easing errors were because I'm a moron and forgot to include jquery.easing library. I also tried to add some functionality where the speed of the scroll depends on how close you are to the center, but I can't seem to get that right either. My math is right, but the distance calculation isn't quite right.